# List View with web view childs not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-webview, android-view

I am using custom ListView and list item contains a WebView. Child WebView's height is `wrap_content` (height is changing as per WebView's contents). When I am scrolling the list view, items' heights are getting disturbed. I have already used View holder. 
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: put some code please.

Comment: Are the item heights changing visually as you scroll, or are the heights simply not matching the content when you scroll to items lower in the list?

Comment: Hi Mohammed & Justin, please check updated image in question block. My listview with different height of webview rows & When I scroll down and up row height get disturbed (Image : First webview row).

Answer (score 0):

In your case the problem is with your adapter.
There is a quick fix :

Do not use the convertView from the getView() method in your adapter.

Replace this :

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view != null) {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    } else {
        final LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_drawer_contracts_list, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }
   }
```

with this:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    View newView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view != null) {
        holder = (ViewHolder) newView.getTag();
    } else {
        final LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        newView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_drawer_contracts_list, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(newView);
        newView.setTag(holder);
    }
```

Caution this is a quick fix , there must be a better way.